# How to identify that a tx is one where an asset of a given policy changed ownership

Tags: cardano-db-sync

By querying db-sync using postgresql queries, how can I identify that a tx is one where an asset of the given policy changed ownership?

Is checking if any asset of the policy is on one address as an input utxo, but on a different address as an output utxo a valid way? If so, is it the only way?